# google experiment - One experiment variant does not appear in the table.

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-experiments

I started a google A/B experiment with 
bla.com/a as the original page
my.bla.com/#/?source=a as the variant page.

I can see the redirection is happening when I land on the original page, but on the result table it's showing 0 sessions on the variant page after 3 days the experiment has been running for.

My variant is a subdomain single page app of the original one. If I change the variant page to my.bla.com without the params it works. Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My educates guess is that "`my.bla.com/#/?source=a`" does not work as variant URL in the report section since Google Analytics tends to ignore everything after the fragment identifier (#). So from the POV of the reporting interface `my.bla.com/#/?source=a` and `my.bla.com` are identical URLs.

It should work if your remove the fragment identifier either in the code or via a view filter. Then you have `my.bla.com/?source=a` as URL, and GA can read query strings just fine.

Comment: Thanks! We couldn't get rid of the # so we eventually resolved it in a different way: my.bla.com/source/a